AWS Lambda function bugs when associated to AWS Cloud Front
I created a static website using S3, CloudFront, Lambda@Edge.
CloudFront is he trigger for Lambda which will log visitor IP adress on a file in S3.
The lambda when tested separately using Function URL it works well and log the data correctly in the S3.
But once the lambda is associated to cloud front I get this message in the front.
Here is the website : www.parrainage-boursorama.net

503 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: swnLdXaY3pciHdg_XnGuDyKRGuULXbPZ3xgCYNT-cxby5qiZh1cXpw==

Here is the code of the Lambda function that works fine when called through funtion url :
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('hello')
    # Extract visitor IP address from CloudFront event
  
    visitor_ip  = event['requestContext']['http']['sourceIp']
    user_agent  = event['requestContext']['http']['userAgent']
    method      = event['requestContext']['http']['method']
    time        = event['requestContext']['time']

    #visitor_ip = str(event)

    
    # Log visitor IP address to an S3 bucket
    bucket_name = 'logs.parrainage-boursorama.net'
    key = 'lambdaLogs/visitor_ips.log'
    
    
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
        existing_data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    except s3.exceptions.NoSuchKey:
        existing_data = ''
    
    # Append visitor IP address to the existing data
    updated_data = existing_data+ f'{time}'+' ### ' + f'{method}'+' ### ' + f'{visitor_ip}'+' ### ' +f'{user_agent}\n'
    
    
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Body=updated_data)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Boursorama Welcome You'
    }


Have you defined any resource-based policies in your Lambda function that permits the CloudFront distribution to invoke it? What  trigger were you using to invoke your lambda@edge?
